# Move image proper distance

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, positioning

I'm trying to move the image in this document precisely 1 inch in from the top and 2 inches in from the left. However, the image has not moved the proper distance. How can I correct that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colorswitch}{5in}
\newcommand{\coverpageimagesize}{5in}

\definecolor{lside}{HTML}{FF88FF}
\definecolor{rside}{HTML}{FF88AA}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[rside] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \fill[lside] ([xshift=-\colorswitch]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-\colorswitch]current page.south east);
  \node[anchor=north west] (a) at (1in,-1in) {\includegraphics[width=\coverpageimagesize, height=\coverpageimagesize]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Current view:

[image]

Comment: You can set the `x` and `y` options for `tikzpicture` to just write numbers as coordinates. For instance, `\begin{tikzpicture}[x=1in,y=1in]`.

Comment: As far as it seems, TikZ uses a coordinate system like in Geometry: positive values ar the right of the anchor, and negative at the left. The same at the top and at the bottom, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working by just adding `shift={(current page.north west)}` as an option for the image. That tells TikZ that the origin should be there. Also, note that the coordinate system in TikZ is just like in Geometry: positive values at the top and right, and negative ones at the left and bottom. I changed the node coordinates to point out that.

Also, note that I removed the units, as I explicitely set them in the `x` and `y` options.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\colorswitch}{5in}
\newcommand{\coverpageimagesize}{5in}

\definecolor{lside}{HTML}{FF88FF}
\definecolor{rside}{HTML}{FF88AA}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,x=1in,y=1in,shift={(current page.north west)}]
  \fill[rside] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \fill[lside] ([xshift=-\colorswitch]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-\colorswitch]current page.south east);
  \node[anchor=north west] (a) at (2,-1) {\includegraphics[width=\coverpageimagesize, height=\coverpageimagesize]{example-image}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is only one problem with your code, which is using absolute coordinate `(1in,-1in)`.

While it is drawing paths `TikZ` uses absolute coordinates and when the diagram is completed, the whole figure is placed as a regular character.

Instruction

```
\node[anchor=north west] (a) at (1in,-1in) 
      {\includegraphics[width=\coverpageimagesize, height=\coverpageimagesize]
      {example-image}};
```

means place `north west` image anchor at absolute position `(1in,-1in)`. This instruction would be perfect if you know where is absolute origin. Where is it?

```
\fill (0,0) circle (2pt) node[right] {(0,0)};
\draw[->] (0,0)|-(1in,-1in);
\node[anchor=north west, draw] (a) at (1in,-1in) ...
```

produces

[image]

So if you expected that origin was page's top left corner, you were wrong and your code fails.

As an alternative you could use `positioning` library and its `below right`  option. If distance between page top left corner and figure top left corner whould be `1in` you could use `below of= 1in of current page.north west` and if distance should be 1in to the right and 1in to the bottom `below of = 1in and 1in of current page.north west`. Both options are shown in following code, select one of them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\colorswitch}{5in}
\newcommand{\coverpageimagesize}{5in}

\definecolor{lside}{HTML}{FF88FF}
\definecolor{rside}{HTML}{FF88AA}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
  \fill[rside] (current page.north west) rectangle (current page.south east);
  \fill[lside] ([xshift=-\colorswitch]current page.north west) rectangle ([xshift=-\colorswitch]current page.south east);
    \node[below right = 1in of current page.north west] (a) {\includegraphics[width=\coverpageimagesize, height=\coverpageimagesize]{example-image}};
    \draw (current page.north west) -- ++(-45:1in);
    \node[below right = 1in and 1in of current page.north west] (a) {\includegraphics[width=\coverpageimagesize, height=\coverpageimagesize]{example-image}};
    \draw (current page.north west) -| ++(1in,-1in);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good explanation! Now I know how to know the origin if it's not explicitly stated! :)